# input text empty when using v-model (update form)

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-blade

Pretty new to vuejs here. I need to make an ajax call (key up event) for a text input in an update form (blade laravel), however in the form the input is blank.

My question is: How do I send the input value from the blade template when the form is loaded to the vue data instance (sn)?

The intention is to alert the user if that value (suite_number) already exists in the database.

Thanks in advance!!!

My blade template:

```
{!! Form::text('suite_number', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>   'suiteNumberLookup', 'v-on:keyup' => 'getSuiteNumber(suite_number, $event)', 'v-model' => 'sn']) !!}
```

My Vuejs:

```
new Vue({
el: '#suiteNumberLookup',
data:
  {
      sn: 'What should I set here to get the data that\'s loaded in the form?'
},
methods: {
    getSuiteNumber(d) {
        this.$http.get('/admin/tenantAjax/getSuiteNumberAjax/' + d).then((response) => {
            // success callback
            //this.tenant = response.data;
            if(response.data){
                this.loaded = true;
            }
            console.log(response.data);
        }, (response) => {
            this.error = response.body;
            this.loadErrorMsg = true;
        });
    }
```